# Need to use two way SSL Mutual Authentication and password authentication alternatively

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, tomcat, spring-security

We have a Springboot application (with embedded tomcat) which exposes certain API's. There are two major access points for these API's. (1) Users (2) Machines

The users needs to access these API's using basic authentication (username & password) on TLS while the Machines need to access these API's using Client Certificates (two-way SSL mutual authentication). I have added the following settings in application.properties

```
server.ssl.key-alias=server
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:server.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=mypass
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.client-auth=want
```

But this is still not allowing access through basic credentials. How do I solve this?